# React Native app was restricted with Driver Distraction in OEM

Tags: android, react-native

I have build app for OEM (Location Based App). When driving started, keep-on popup coming like **You can't use this feature while driving**. How to whitelist my app from this blocker.

Does any configuration required in android manifest file?

```
react - 18.2.0
react-native - 0.72.7
```